# How to connect signal and slot in different classes in Qt?

Tags: qt, signals-slots

I have two simple `classes`(`class A` and `class B`).
In `a.h`, I just declared a `QPushButton`:

```
QPushButton *testBtn = new QPushButton(this);
```

In `b.h`:

```
class B : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit B(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    A testingA;
public slots:
    void testing();
};
```

and `b.cpp`:

```
B::B(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    connect(testingA.testBtn, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &B::testing);
}

void B::testing()
{
    qDebug() << "testing";
}
```

I am trying to connect the `signal` in `class A` to the `slot` in `class B`, but from the code I provide, it's not working. 
So what is the right way to do it? 
Thanks

**Edit:**
According to PRIME's answer, I made a few changes. 
In A's constructor, added:

```
connect(testBtn, &QPushButton::clicked, [this](){OnButtonClicked();});
```

to emit the own defined `OnButtonClicked()` `signal`;
and in B's construtor, changed to this:

```
connect(&testingA, &A::OnButtonClicked, this, &B::testing);
```

But when I clicked the button, the `testing` `slot` still not triggered.

**Edit 2:**
After doing some researches and trying a few times, I found that if I created `B`'s `object` in `A`'s `constructor`, and then connect `A`'s signal to `B`'s `slot` in `A`, it will work. 
But I really can not figure out why I can not connect `A`'s signal to `B`'s `slot` in `B`. 
This is what's in the `main.cpp`:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    B b;
    A w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Is that because of some reasons that `A`'s object is out of scope in `B`?
Can someone tell me where I did wrong? Thanks so much.

Comment: you have 2 objects of the class `A`: `testingA` and `w`?

Comment: @eyllanesc, yes, I declared a `testingA` object in `B`'s constructor in order to connect `A`'s `signal` in `B`'s constructor. Something wrong with this?

Comment: @eyllanesc I think I figured out where I did wrong now. I removed the object w of `A`, and I created one `testingA` in `B`'s constructor and make it show on screen. And then it worked.

Comment: @eyllanesc If you do not mind, allow me to ask, what if that `A`'s `signal` has to be used in more than one class, I guess it will be wrong to create `A`'s objects in other classes. Then what is the proper way to do that?

Comment: I do not understand your question, my question was because I think you are thinking that the signal associated with `testing` and `w` are the same, but that is not true, the classes are abstractions and the objects are the ones that really exist, what each object of the class `A` will have its own signal.

Comment: @eyllanesc The question I asked is how to connect `A`'s signal to `B`'s `slot` in `class B`, and then I tried to create `A`'s object in `class B` and connected the signal and slot, and in `main.cpp`, I only created `B`'s object, so it worked. But I got confused with some concepts, for example: what if `class A` contains some basic layout of a program, and the rest of the `class`es need to connect to `A`'s `signal`, what is the right way to do this? Hope I explain my new question clearly.

Comment: the classes are not connected, the signals are declared in the classes but the classes are abstractions, so if you want to continue with the discussion do not talk about class A with signal, say the object of class A has a signal, the same happens with the slots

Comment: @eyllanesc So what if other objects of some `class`es have some slots and want to connect to `class A`'s object's signals, what is the right way to do so? Because you can not connect signals and slots in 'main.cpp', all those things have to be done in some `class`es?  I am just getting confused how to do it properly.

Comment: You can make the connection where both objects exist, if you are within the implementation of a class that inherits from `QObject` as for example the widget just `connect(sender, &ClaseSender::signal, receiver, &ClaseReceiver::slot_and_or_signal)`, iif you are outside of the implementation of a class that inherits from QObject like for example main.cpp you must do the following: `QObject::connect(sender, &ClassSender::signal, receiver, &ClaseReceiver::slot_and_or_signal)`

Comment: Read the following to have more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20932376/difference-between-qobjectconnect-vs-connect-methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do it like this, hide your button in the class A, emit your own defined signal from class A lets call it OnButtonClicked.

Cascading code(inside A's c'tor):

```
connect(testBtn , &QPushButton::clicked, [this](){OnButtonClicked();});
```

You will also have to declare this new signal in class A now:
So class A must have folowing besides whatever it has right now:

```
class A
{
Q_OBJECT
signals:
    void OnButtonClicked();
};
```

No special slot is needed since you are using a Lambda as a slot for the signal OnButtonClicked.

Connection in class B( do it in the c'tor ):

```
connect(testingA, &A::OnButtonClicked, this, &B::testing);
```

Comment: I tried the way you provided, but I got this error:  `no matching function for call to 'B::connect(A&, void (A::*)(), B*, void (B::*)())'
     connect(testingA, &A::OnButtonClicked, this, &B::testing);`, why is that?

Comment: @TheodoreTang: Did you declare the signal "OnButtonClicked" in the header of A?
See the edit.

Answer (score 2):

You can connect signal-to-signal in your sender object, for example widget containing the button:

```
class MyWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QPushButton *pushButton;
public:
    explicit MyWidget(QWidget *parent = nullptr) : QWidget(parent), pushButton(new QPushButton(this)) {
        connect(pushButton, &QPushButton::click, this, &MyWidget::buttonClicked);
    }

signals:

    void buttonClicked();

public slots:
};
```

By the way you would normally send signals by using `emit` keyword, e.g.:

```
emit buttonClicked();
```

Then the consumer:

```
class TestObject : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit TestObject(QObject *parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent) { }

public slots:

    void onButtonClicked() {
        qDebug() << "clicked";
    }
};
```

And connect both instances:

```
MyWidget widget;
TestObject to;

QObject::connect(&widget, &MyWidget::buttonClicked, &to, &TestObject::onButtonClicked);
```

Answer (score 0):

in your class A you should use the signal `testing` of the class B, if you clicked on your button the OnButtonClicked function will be activated

```
A:
public slots:
    void OnButtonClicked();

void A::OnButtonClicked()
{
    ...
    emit testing(1);
}

B:
signals:
    void testing(int level);
```

then to connect both you can do this

```
connect(startButton, &QPushButton::clicked, board, &A::OnButtonClicked);
```