# QObject::connect, when the prefix can be ommitted

Tags: qt

In many cases, `QObject::connect()` is used as a whole to create a connection of signal and slot, e.g.:

```
QLabel *label = new QLabel;
QScrollBar *scrollBar = new QScrollBar;
QObject::connect(scrollBar, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),
                 label,  SLOT(setNum(int)));
```

But I have noted there are some cases where the prefix `QObject::` can be ommitted. For example, in creating dialogs (with `QDialog`), `connect()` can be directly used without the prefix.  Is there any other similar situation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between QObject::connect vs connect methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20932376/difference-between-qobjectconnect-vs-connect-methods)

Answer (score 1):

***Background: Understanding static member functions***

First, let's take a step back and think about **static member functions** in C++. As an example, suppose we have a class named `MyClass`, with a static member function named `myStaticFunction()`.

From inside a member function of `MyClass` (or a subclass of `MyClass`), there are 3 ways to call the example function:

- `MyClass::myStaticFunction()`
- `this->myStaticFunction()`
- `myStaticFunction()`

However, from outside a member function of `MyClass` (or a subclass of `MyClass`), there is only 1 way to call the example function:

- `MyClass::myStaticFunction()`

***QObject::connect() is a static member function***

> For example, in creating dialogs (with `QDialog`), `connect()` can be directly used without the prefix.

This has almost nothing to do with creating dialogs at all.

Remember, the `QObject` class has a static member function called `connect()`*. Also remember that `QDialog` is a subclass of `QObject`.

Therefore, from inside a member function of a `QObject` subclass, there are 3 ways to call `connect()`:

- `QObject::connect(...)`
- `this->connect(...)`
- `connect(...)`

However, from outside a member function of a `QObject` subclass (such as in the main() function), there is only 1 way to call `connect()`:

- `QObject::connect(...)`

**To be precise, there are many overloads of `connect()`, including non-static versions. However, we're only focussing on the static versions.*